# Finding the coefficient of $x^{2014}$ in a $2014$ degree polynomial

Tags: functions, polynomials, contest-math

Let $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ be two $2014$ degree polynomials such that $f(n)+(-1)^n g(n)=2^n$ for $n=1,2,3,....,4030$. Find the leading coefficient of $x^{2014}$ in $g(x)$.

I am not getting any clue on how to start with this. $f(2n)+g(2n)=2^{2n}=4^n$ while $f(2n+1)-g(2n+1)= 2\cdot4^n$ How to proceed with this information?

Comment: Hint: The polynomial $S(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ has degree $2014$ and we know $2015$ values of it; it's therefore possible to get an exact formula for it. Similarly for the polynomial $D(x) = f(x)-g(x)$.

Comment: Another approach, at least to guess the answer, is to replace $2014$ and $4030$ with $k$ and $2k+2$ and work out the answer for small values of $k$ to see if you spot a pattern.

Comment: My first try, for such a problem would be to strive to develop my intuition with respect to the problem's constraints, by using the comment of @GregMartin.  Personally, I would immediately try to see what happens if (for example) $~k = 6.$

Comment: The quality of your posting is borderline, with respect to MathSE protocol.  Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Answer (score 1):

The first step you took is a good one because, as Greg Martin points out in the comments, you now have polynomials $h_1(x) = f(2x)+g(2x)$ and $h_2(x) = f(2x-1)-g(2x-1)$ of degrees (at most) $2014$ and you know their values at $2015$ distinct points. This completely determines polynomials $h_1$ and $h_2$ by [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Now, by solving appropriate linear system, you get $g(x) = \frac 12(h_1(\frac x2)-h_2(\frac{x+1}2)).$

This solves your problem in principle and really, you could just give it to software and produce the solution. To get the result by hand, there's bit more trickery we can employ to side-step basically all tedious calculations.

Let's first determine $h_1$. Since we know that $h(n) = 4^n,\ n = 1,\ldots,2015;$ write $$h_1(x) = a_0+a_1(x-1)+a_2(x-1)(x-2)+\ldots +a_{2014}(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-2014).$$ This form is useful since plugging in values $n=1,2,\ldots,2015$ will give us triangular $2015\times 2015$ linear system

\begin{align}
4^1 &= a_0\\
4^2 &= a_0+a_1\\
4^3 &= a_0 + 2a_1 + 2a_2\\
&\ \ \vdots\\
4^{2015} &= a_0 +2014\,a_1+\ldots +2014!\,a_{2014}
\end{align} At this point, you can start solving for $a_i$ one by one, notice a pattern and prove general formula for $a_n$ by induction (it's actually not that hard to spot the pattern). Still, this is lots of calculations and luckily, since the left hand side is always of the form $4^n$, we can be bit smarter and by some rewriting, we can easily find a solution to the above system. Regularity of the system will make sure that it's unique.

We have $h_1(x) = a_0+\sum_{k= 1}^{\color{blue}{2014}}a_k\prod_{i=1}^k(x-i),$ so, $h_1(n) = a_0+\sum_{k= 1}^{\color{blue}{2014}}a_k\prod_{i=1}^k(n-i)$. Note that $\prod_{i=1}^k(n-i) = 0$ when $k\geq n$, so we have $$h_1(n) = a_0+\sum_{k= 1}^{\color{blue}{n-1}}a_k\prod_{i=1}^k(n-i) = \sum_{k= 0}^{{n-1}}a_k\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-k)!} = \sum_{k= 0}^{{n-1}}a_k\,k!\binom{n-1}k.$$ Finally, $$\sum_{k= 0}^{{n}}a_k\,k!\binom{n}k = h_1(n+1) = 4^{n+1} = 4(3+1)^n = 4\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk 3^k$$ which implies that $a_k\,k! = 4\cdot 3^k$ will solve our linear system.

---

I will leave the work to determine $h_2$ to you, since you can employ the same method.

What remains is to calculate the leading coefficient of $g$. We know that the leading coefficient of $h_1$ is $a_{2014}$, and let $b_{2014}$ be the leading coefficient of $h_2$. Then,
\begin{align}
g(x) &= \frac 12\left(h_1\left(\frac x2\right)-h_2\left(\frac{x+1}2\right)\right)\\ &= \frac 12\left(\left(a_{2014}\frac{x^{2014}}{2^{2014}}+\small\text{lower degree terms}\right)-\left(b_{2014}\frac{(x+1)^{2014}}{2^{2014}}+\small\text{lower degree terms}\right)\right)
\end{align}

which, hopefully, is enough for you to finish the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define
$$\begin{align}
&p(x) :=f(2x)+g(2x)\\
&q(x):=2(f(2x-1)-g(2x-1))
\end{align}$$
then $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are two polynomials of degree of **at most** $2014$ .

We have for $n = 1,...,2015$
$$\begin{align}
&p(n) :=f(2n)+g(2n) = 2^{2n}\\
&q(n):=2(f(2n-1)-g(2n-1))=2\cdot 2^{2n-1} = 2^{2n}\\
\end{align}$$

The two **at-most-** $2014$-degree polynomials are equal at $2015$ values $x =1,2,...,2015$, then they must be equal:
$$\color{red}{p(x) = q(x) \hspace{2cm}\forall x\in \mathbb{R}}\tag{1}$$

Denote $a_{2014}$ and $b_{2014}$ the coefficient of $x^{2014}$ in $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, we study the leading coeeficient of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ :
$$\begin{align}
(1)&\implies a_{2014}\cdot (2x)^{2014}+b_{2014}\cdot (2x)^{2014}=2\left( a_{2014}\cdot (2x)^{2014}-b_{2014}\cdot (2x)^{2014} \right)\\
&\iff a_{2014}+b_{2014} = 2(a_{2014}-b_{2014})\\
&\iff \color{red}{a_{2014} = 3b_{2014}} \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

---

Now, we find the leading coefficient of $p(x)$ by using [Lagrande polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Definition) at $2015$ points  $\left(j,4^j  \right)_{j=1,...,2015}$, the leading coefficient $p_{2014}$ is equal to:

$$\begin{align}
p_{2014} &= \sum_{j=1}^{2015}\left(4^j\prod_{1\le m \ne j \le 2015}\frac{1}{j-m}\right) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{2015}\left(4^j\prod_{1\le m < j}\frac{1}{j-m}\prod_{j< m \le 2015}\frac{1}{j-m}\right)\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{2015}\left(4^j\frac{1}{(j-1)!}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{2015-j
}}{(2015-j)!}\right)\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{2015}\left(4^j\frac{1}{(j-1)!}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{2014-(j-1)
}}{(2014-(j-1))!}\right)\\
&= 4\sum_{j=0}^{2014}\left(4^j\cdot(-1)^{2014-j}\frac{1}{j!}\cdot\frac{1}{(2014-j)!}\right)\\
&= 4\frac{1}{2014!}\sum_{j=0}^{2014}\left(4^j\cdot(-1)^{2014-j}\cdot 
 \pmatrix{2014 \\ j }\right)\\
&= 4\frac{1}{2014!} \cdot (4-1)^{2014} \\
\color{red}{p_{2014}} &\color{red}{= 4\cdot\frac{3^{2014}}{2014!}}  \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

---

Return to the leading coefficient $a_{2014}$ and $b_{2014}$ in $p(x)$, we have:
$$\begin{align}
p_{2014} &= a_{2014}\cdot 2^{2014}+b_{2014}\cdot 2^{2014}\\
\color{red}{p_{2014}}&\color{red}{\stackrel{(2)}{=} b_{2014}\cdot 4\cdot 2^{2014}} \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

From $(3) $ and $(4)$ we deduce that
$$\color{red}{b_{2014} =\frac{1}{2014!} \left( \frac{3}{2}\right)^{2014}}$$

Q.E.D